# Chart - Zoom In to show more precise data

Tags: c#, winforms, graph, charts, zooming

So I have a chart at the moment that carries quite a lot of data. 
This can be seen in the image below:

[image]

Basically I want the user to be able to zoom in and see further into the data. 
As you can tell it is currently carrying a large amount of data already.

I would like the user to be able to zoom and see more precise things.

```
protected void drawChart()
    {


        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Clear();

        foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView1.Columns)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(col.HeaderText);
        }

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            DataRow dRow = dt.NewRow();
            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
            {
                dRow[cell.ColumnIndex] = cell.Value;
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(dRow);
        }


        chart1.DataBind();

        chart1.DataSource = dt;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalAutoMode = 
                             IntervalAutoMode.VariableCount;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Angle = 90;
        chart1.Series["Series1"].XValueMember = "Date/Time";

        chart1.Series["Series1"].YValueMembers = "HeartRate";

        chart1.Series["Series2"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
        chart1.Series["Series2"].YValueMembers = "Speed";

        chart1.Series["Series3"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
        chart1.Series["Series3"].YValueMembers = "Cadence";

        chart1.Series["Series4"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
        chart1.Series["Series4"].YValueMembers = "Altitude";

        chart1.Series["Series5"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
        chart1.Series["Series5"].YValueMembers = "Pressure";

        chart1.Series["Series6"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
        chart1.Series["Series6"].YValueMembers = "Power";

        chart1.Series["Series1"].LegendText = "Heart Rate";

        chart1.Series["Series1"].ToolTip =
         "Heart Rate:#VALY\nAverage:#AVG\nMinimum:#MIN\nMaximum:#MAX ";

        chart1.Series["Series2"].LegendText = "Speed";
        chart1.Series["Series2"].ToolTip = 
         "Speed(KM/H):#VALY\nAverage:#AVG\nMaximum:#MAX";

        chart1.Series["Series3"].LegendText = "Cadence";
        chart1.Series["Series3"].ToolTip = 
         "Cadence:#VALY\nAverage:#AVG\nMaximum:#MAX";

        chart1.Series["Series4"].LegendText = "Altitude";
        chart1.Series["Series4"].ToolTip =  
         "Altitude(KM/H):#VALY\nAverage:#AVG\nMaximum:#MAX";

        chart1.Series["Series5"].LegendText = "Pressure";
        chart1.Series["Series5"].ToolTip = 
         "Pressure:#VALY\nAverage:#AVG\nMaximum:#MAX";

        chart1.Series["Series6"].LegendText = "Power";
        chart1.Series["Series6"].ToolTip = 
          "Power:#VALY\nAverage:#AVG\nMaximum:#MAX";

        // add the highlight series after databinding!! (**)
        Series sz = chart1.Series.Add("Interval");
        sz.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Point;
        sz.Color = Color.Red;
        sz.BorderWidth = 3;

        foreach (DataPoint dp in chart1.Series[0].Points)
        {
            if (dp.YValues[0] == 0) sz.Points.AddXY(dp.XValue, 0);
        }

        // allow zooming: (Taw's edit)
        chart1.Series["Series1"].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;
        chart1.Series["Series1"].CursorX.AutoScroll = true;
        chart1.Series["Series1"].CursorX.IsUserSelectionEnabled = true;          


   }
```

Comment: So what's stopping you?

Comment: Which graphics lib to you use? (please add tag)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is easy but it does take a few settings to do the trick:

```
ChartArea CA = chart1.ChartAreas[0];  // quick reference
CA.AxisX.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;
CA.CursorX.AutoScroll = true;
CA.CursorX.IsUserSelectionEnabled = true;
```

Now the user can drag the mouse over an area of interest and it will be zoomed in to fill the Chart:

[image][image]

Note the small button on the left of the horizontal scrollbar: This resets the range.

As ever so often with `Chart` the problem is the not exactly well structured documentation..

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77095/discussion-on-answer-by-taw-chart-zoom-in-to-show-more-precise-data).