# Get Y value of series from the X Cursor position where a ChartArea is clicked on

Tags: c#, charts

I would like to get the Y Value for a series corresponding to the X position of a ChartArea that the user has clicked-upon.

I have tried to capture the X position of the mouse within the chartarea that is clicked upon but I am getting NaN returned for the result:

```
 private void chart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       double XVal = chart.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.Position;
    }
```

Once I have got the X position in the chartarea where the user has clicked the mouse, I would then like to use that to get the Y value of a series at that x-position.

Comment: What kind of object is Position? It's probably not a number if you get "NaN"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **What is wrong with you code?**

As for [`chart.ChartAreas[0].CursorX`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.cursor%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): A `Chart Cursor` is an object created by and used for [zooming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29985796/chart-zoom-in-to-show-more-precise-data/29986941?s=1|4.4164#29986941) and which then

> Represents a horizontal or vertical line that defines a position along
>   an axis.

So it has not much to do with the mouse cursor and is not valid when not zooming or (when zooming is disabled) for selecting.

- **How to solve your problem then?**

There are a few options you have; unfortunately none are both simple **and** exactly what you asked for.

**One** simple thing is to use the `HitTest` for `Charts`:

```
private void chart1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    HitTestResult hit = chart1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
    if (hit.PointIndex >= 0)
        infoLabel.Text = "Over DataPoint No " +  hit.PointIndex;
}
```

This is simple and safe but will work only when the cursor is actually **over** a `DataPoint`. How well it suits you may depend on the `ChartType`; Very well for `Columns` or `Bars` but not so well for `Points` or `Bubbles`..

**And** you could call `PixelPositionToValue`:

```
private void chart1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var xv =  chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.PixelPositionToValue(e.X);                    
    var yv =  chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.PixelPositionToValue(e.Y);
    infoLabel.Text = "x = " +  xv + "   y =" + yv;
}
```

In [theory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.axis.pixelpositiontovalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) this is only safe to call from one of the `Paint` events but in practice it seems to work fine when called from user interactions as well. (If you run into problems you could do a [dummy call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30247240/get-coordinates-of-a-drawing-point-from-chart-values-in-textboxes/30248038?s=1|0.4908#30248038) on one of the `Paint` events and abort it with a flag after pulling the value(s) you want; the example does a lot more than what you need, but I doubt it will be necessary at all..)

However it will only bring back the **`Values` according to the axis**, not the nearest `DataPoint`. If you really need to get at the actual `DataPoint` you would then have to do a search over the `Points` of your `Series`..:

```
Series S = chart1.Series[0];            // short reference
DataPoint pPrev = S.Points.Select(x => x)
                        .Where(x => x.XValue >= xv)
                        .DefaultIfEmpty(S.Points.First()).First();
DataPoint pNext = S.Points.Select(x => x)
                        .Where(x => x.XValue <= xv)
                        .DefaultIfEmpty(S.Points.Last()).Last();
```

This should bring up the previous and next `DataPoint`. It is up to you to decide which one to use..

Comment: Thanks, however I should have added i'm using .NET 3.5, and Points doesn't appear to have a Select method, or the First and Last methods.

Comment: These are LINQ methods, so make sure to include the namespace: `using System.Linq;`

Answer (score 0):

First convert the mouse click position to a relative position:

```
x= 100.0 * e.X / chart.Width
```

Then convert relative position to axis position:

```
double xMin= axis.Minimum;
double xMax= axis.Maximum;
double pMin= axis.GetPosition(xMin);
double pMax= axis.GetPosition(xMax);
xx= (x-pMin) * (xMax-xMin) / (pMax-pMin) + xMin;
```

Then use the axis position to probe the series (eg interpolate or nearest point as you like)

Comment: can you explain more about `axis` ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a MouseClick-Handler for your chart control instead of a normal Click-Handler, because of the "MouseEventArgs":

```
private void chart1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    //check where you clicked, returns different information like the clicked series name and the index of the clicked point
    HitTestResult clicked = chart1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
    //this is how you get your y-Value
    double yValue = chart1.Series[clicked.Series.Name].Points[clicked.PointIndex].YValues[0];
}
```